# Android 4.4 (API 19) not show local notification

Tags: android, notifications, local

Does not show local notification on the android kitkat (API 19). On the newer version or even on the API 16 it works fine

```
NotificationCompat.Builder nt = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
nt.setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
        .setContentText(tr)
        .setSmallIcon(getApplicationInfo().icon)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
        .setAutoCancel(true);

nt.getNotification().flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

nm.notify(1,nt.build());
```

What am I doing wrong ?!

Comment: make sure that it is not device-specific problem.

Comment: I'm testing on two devices and an emulator.
Device API 21 - shows
Emulator API 16 - shows
Emulator API 19 - does not work

Comment: Go to app settings page and see if notifications are enabled?

Comment: Please share your complete code

Comment: Checked, notifications enabled.
Here is the service code: 
https://pastebin.com/SqeQ83J3